# Timing the interval between touchEvents

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, ontouchlistener

Ok, so I have a TextView that have attached a TouchListener to. The idea is to press on the TextView 5 times within 700 miliseconds and if this happens the Activity fires off an intent that sends the user to a different activity. I store the variables for keeping track of time and a counter at the top of the Activity like this:

```
int counter = 0;  // for touch event
long start = 0, stop = 0;
```

The onTouch method looks like this:

```
View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                start += event.getEventTime();
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                stop += event.getEventTime();
                counter++;
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Counter is : " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(counter == 5){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "stop - start " + (stop - start), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if((stop - start) < 700) {
                        counter = 0; start = 0; stop = 0;  // reset counter and time variables

                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        counter = 0; start = 0; stop = 0;  // reset counter and time variables
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
    mAppTitle.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

mAppTitle is the TextView. The problem is that I want the first touch to record a time and once that time exceeds the 700 milliseconds the variables should reset to 0. Right now, if the user only clicks 4 times the counter stays at 4 and doesn't reset until you click it one more time. I know there is probably a better way to implement this using Threads and Runnables but I'm new to Java/Android and the documentation out there sucks....to me at least.

EDIT: I just realized that getEventTime() isn't actually starting a timer, it's simply recording the duration between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP. This must be where you would set a Thread instead of getEventTime right?

Answer (score 0):

I once had to solve the same problem. I did it by filling an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with `Timestamp`s.

Declaring a queue (in `onCreate()`, for example):

```
private ArrayBlockingQueue<Timestamp> timeStampQueue;
```

Initializing the queue and setting its capacity:

```
timeStampQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(4); // number of clicks necessary - 1
```

Inside the listener, filling the queue (in any case) and starting the intent (in case the time of the current event is less than .7 seconds "away" from the time of the first event):

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
if (timeStampQueue.remainingCapacity() == 0) {
    Timestamp oldestTimestamp = timeStampQueue.poll();
    if ((timestamp.getTime() - oldestTimestamp.getTime()) < 700) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
timeStampQueue.add(timestamp);
```

If you are listening only for one kind of touch or click event on your view you don't need to differentiate between action types.

Using a timer does not work here, for the following reason: If you start a timer on occasion of the first event, you may be able to check if four more events took place after it started running. However, in case that within the threshold there were less than four more events, you have no way to compare the time of the second event to the time of the sixth event since you did not keep track of the time of the second event. You would have to start four timers or, to stay more on the efficient side, keep four timestamps - in a FIFO structure like a queue.

Comment: :: The official recommendation is to use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`. How ever unlikely it may be for the system time to change in that 700 ms it is good practice to follow these recommendations. ==> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html